# Pure java server application for enterprise start-up

Tags: java, spring, client-server, struts

Is a simple pure java server application is enough to handle request from android and windows .net client or do i have to follow any special frameworks.

And also in case pure java server is enough how to make a secure authentication (is there any way to send user login info without using normal outputstream like that).

I am not interested in creating a web based http application, so for me suggest a good framework on java or any other programming framework to develop server software that will cope with other client applications

Comment: Your question is both too broad and unclear.

Comment: If the application can read data from the clients, and write data back, you don't have to use anything in particular. It's not really clear what you're asking for, though. What's "a request from a client"? HTTP? Sockets? "Secure authentication" just means encryption and hashing; there are a million ways to do that. There are only relatively few ways of doing all of this *well*, which is why there are libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference for you to use the Web services and create a service oriented architecture for the server end. By this way,

1. This will enable you to focus on the business logic
2. You can use standard web authentication mechanisms
3. You don't have to focus on server implementation or client handling.
4. Upto the industrial standards and common practices.
5. Integration to other environments becomes much easier.

But if you still want to use an pure socket based server check on fo the following for Java.

1. [Netty](http://netty.io/)
2. [Apache Mina](https://mina.apache.org/)
3. [Project Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/)

NOTE: Also check the `nodejs` which actually uses HTTP. This might interest you for sure.